# Is it possible to run Android app after press Power off button?

Tags: android

I'm finding a solutiion to run Android app when user press turn off button. Instead of turn off screen of power off mobile, it will launch a special app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK won't allow for that, sorry, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/pNtN7xvaqNk)